# How do I setup firebase password authentication for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication for a web app, thus I have both Email/Password, Google and Facebook sign-in providers enabled and working in my Firebase project. Now I try to get Firebase authentication working for a Flutter app in the same project but I cannot get it to work, and since I'm new to Flutter I'm not really sure how to proceed.

I have added [Firebase to my flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios) and then added [firebase_auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start) to it.

In my code I do:

```
void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
     options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  auth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: app);

  runApp(const SimpleWebview());
}
```

and then later:

```
auth.idTokenChanges().listen((User? user) {
  if (user == null) {
    print('User is currently signed out!');
  } else {
    print('User is signed in!');
  }
});
```

And on email/password input:

```
void _handleLogin() async {
   try {
      print("start login");
      final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
         email: nameController.text, password: passwordController.text);
      print("LOGIN OK");
      print(credential);
   } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
         print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
         print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
   } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
   }
   print("hmm...");
}
```

All I get from this, both in emulator and real device, is:

```
flutter: User is currently signed out!
flutter: start login
flutter: hmm...
```

since I don't get any exceptions or anything my guess is that firebase-auth is installed ok but somehow not connected with my ios app (I've only tried on ios so far, not android). But besides running `flutterfire configure` and following the instructions I'm not sure what to do, and not sure how to find the issue either. Hoping for some guidance...

One thing I noticed (maybe completely irrelevant) is that when I do flutterfire configure I get:

```
MacBook-Pro:xxwrapper mycomp$ flutterfire configure
i Found 1 Firebase projects.                                                                                                                                                              
✔ Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · xxproj (xxproj)                                                                                                  
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios                                                                                    
i Firebase android app com.xx.xxwrapper registered.                                                                                                                              
i Firebase ios app com.xx.xxwrapper.ImageNotification registered.                                                                                                                

Firebase configuration file lib/firebase_options.dart generated successfully with the 
following Firebase apps:

Platform  Firebase App Id
android   1:330123456789:android:82077c3972090925b30000
ios       1:330129876543:ios:56fdd459c10b9fbdb30000
```

What strikes me as strange here is that for ios only the `com.xx.xxwrapper.ImageNotification` app is listed (which is just a Notification Service Extension I had to create in order to get Firebase messaging to show images in notifications). My real ios app, com.xx.xxwrapper, is not picked up by flutterfire configure.